# can't apply CSS rules to bootstrap collapsible menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

on [this](http://passpaeds.com/y/) site, if you shrink the browser window & make the toggle buttons appear, & then click one (either one), you'll see the resulting dropdowns only fill a small proportion of the screen width.   i want them both to stretch to fill 100% of it.

i've messed around trying to set CSS styles by typing them directly into the firebug console.   example: typing the following works increases the font size & (strangely) the width of the dropdown menu (bigger text, more space it takes)...

```
$('.collapse.in').css({"font-size":"20pt"});
```

but i can't seem to affect the width of the dropdown (uncollapsed) menu's themselves

am i missing something obvious?

Comment: Make sure your custom CSS stylings, present in the JS, are loaded after Bootstrap finishes loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying you want the lists to span 100% of the div container? Is this a site you're working on? If so, are the floats necessary? I have to ask, because I can't imagine why you'd want to float if you want lists to occupy the entire space. If you remove the floats that you have, the list, being a block level element, will naturally fill 100% of the parent div.

Comment: i want the lists to span 100% of the browser/screen width (so yes).  yes, its a (cursed) site i'm working on.  are the floats necessary?  i thought so.  they make the 2 navbar elements - unordered list & search box - appear on a single line on larger screen widths.  the latter had a habit of dropping down onto the next line & making the navigation menu very tall (not a good look).  HOWEVER.  saying what u said gave me the idea of using a media query to make the floats _only_ kick in for larger screen widths (ie: when the toggle buttons aren't there).   & it works.  cheers dude

Comment: Ah, fair enough. I'd only really looked at hamburger breakpoint. Glad to hear you got it worked out :)